# Javascript: Error "Cannot set property '...' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, syntax-error

I'm farely new to Javascript and I was trying to create a terrain  generator. When setting some values in a 2D array this error, Cannot set property '4.5' of undefined", which is odd since I already initialized the array with 0's.
This is the what's giving me trouble:

```
this.terrainArr[y + (size - 1) / 2][x + (size - 1) / 2] = 
(this.terrainArr[y][x] +
 this.terrainArr[y + (size - 1)][x] +
 this.terrainArr[y + (size - 1)][x + (size - 1)] +
 this.terrainArr[y][x + (size - 1)]) / 4 + 
((Math.random() * (delta + 1)) - (delta / 2));
```

And I initialize the array like this:

```
this.terrainArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < this.size; i++) {
    var column = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < this.size; j++) {
        column[j] = 0;
    }
    this.terrainArr[i] = column;
}
```

I call the functions one after the other

```
this.initArr();
this.calcTerrain(0, 0, this.size, 10);
```

Does someone know what's going on?

Comment: Just use a debugger. Probably, `y + (size - 1) / 2` is not in the `[0, this.size)` interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If size is even, y + (size - 1) / 2 will not be an integer. Trying to read a non-integer index of an array will return undefined; and trying to use index notation on undefined will throw an Error.

For example:

```
myArray[2.5][4.5] // this is equivalent to undefined[4.5] which will throw
```